# Pass touch events through service overlay view

Tags: android, view, android-service

I have a Service which displays some info and a button over the system screens. I want touch events to pass through the Service view and act normally on the apps/screens below it. This is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEXT GOES HERE"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:text="button"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Service Code:

```
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;


        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowManager.addView(myView, params);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want touch events to pass through the Service view and act normally on the apps/screens below it

Fortunately, this is no longer possible. What you are describing is a tapjacking attack, where an app spies on user input while still allowing that input to proceed normall. This has been blocked for several years, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the info!